# How to get detailed error message from Alchemy using ethersJS

Tags: ethers.js, alchemy

I am using Alchemy as my RPC URL node provider, my connected address currently has 0 ETH for gas.

When I try to run a transaction that requires gas in a `try-catch` block, I error I catch is

> Error: Internal JSON-RPC error

However, when I look at Alchemy's dashboard for details, it gives a more detailed error of

> Code: -32000 Message:    insufficient funds for gas * price + value

which is actually the detailed error message I am looking for so that I can handle it in my frontend app.

Is there a way to get the detailed error message in my frontend app using ethersJS instead of the generic `Internal JSON-RPC error`?

Comment: can you share some details on the code you're using to run the transaction?

Comment: Also, I wonder if this is a change that needs to happen at the ethers.js level in order to support the more detailed error message..

Comment: started an issue to track/discuss in the ethers.js github repo here: https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/3216

Answer (score 2):

If you're using ethers.js, you can use [ethers-decode-error](https://github.com/superical/ethers-decode-error) to handle the detailed error message in your frontend quite easily.

Install `ethers-decode-error`:

```
npm install ethers-decode-error --save
```

And then just decode the error in your `try/catch block`, for example:

```typescript
import { ErrorDecoder } from 'ethers-decode-error'

const errorDecoder = ErrorDecoder.create()

const WETH = new ethers.Contract('0xC02aa...756Cc2', abi, provider)
try {
  const tx = await WETH.transfer('0x0', amount)
  await tx.wait()
} catch (err) {
  const { type, name, reason } = await errorDecoder.decode(err)

  // Prints "Error type: RpcError"
  console.log('Error type:', type)
  // Prints "Error name: -32000"
  console.log('Error name:', name)
  // Prints "Error reason: insufficient funds for gas * price + value"
  console.log('Error reason:', reason)
}
```

It's quite straightforward. You can get the actual error message from the `reason` property of the decoded error. There are [other information](https://github.com/superical/ethers-decode-error?tab=readme-ov-file#decoded-error) related to the error that can be used for handling the error too.

You can see more examples of handling errors [here](https://github.com/superical/ethers-decode-error?tab=readme-ov-file#examples).

### Playground Demo

Here's an actual code sandbox demo of using `ethers-decode-error` to handle errors when calling against the `DAI` contract on Ethereum mainnet using the Alchemy RPC: [https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/youthful-drake-f5lfcp](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/youthful-drake-f5lfcp?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A9%2C1)

Click the "Run Erroneous Transaction" button to send a transaction that will revert to see the error obtained.

[image: Screenshot of the actual demo]

And if you were to proceed with sending the transaction without sufficient funds as what the asker had probably done, you will get the clean detailed error like so:

[image]

Comment: This library requires the field that the Alchemy RPC doesn't include in the error so this wont work

Comment: @Sid I have used the Alchemy RPC and it seems to work. I have updated the answer to include a codesandbox demo and screenshot using Alchemy RPC to extract the detailed error message. https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/youthful-drake-f5lfcp

Comment: I spoke to the Alchemy team and they confirmed that they don't include the custom errors as it's optional in the RPC spec

Comment: @Sid Would you mind sharing which field you are referring to? I’ve used Alchemy RPC in the demo above and it worked fine.